# Element-wise Multiplication of (x,y,1) * (x,y)

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication, elementwise-operations

```
matrixADimensions = matrixA.shape # returns [901,1249,1]
matrixBDimensions = matrixB.shape # returns [901,1249]
```

I am trying to get the element-wise multiplication of matrixA and matrixB but I am getting the error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (901,1249,1) (901,1249)`.

I believe it has something to do with the dimensions of both matrices since they are not the same. Actually, technically they are the same since `[901,1249,1]` is the same thing as `[901,1249]` but Python does not seem to know this.

How can I multiply matrixA with matrixB?

Comment: `matrixA[:,:,0] * matrixB` should work.

Comment: Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.squeeze`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) to remove single-dimensional entries from the shape of your array. So in your case, you would do:

```
import numpy as np

np.squeeze(matrixA) * matrixB
```

This has the advantage of not needing to know the position of your single-dimensional entry in your array shape (unlike taking an indexing approach such as `matrixA[:,:,0]`).